# Why Url.Action is not recognized as Child Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am displaying a image from database in MVC using the following code in my view

```
<img alt="@Html.Raw(m.Title)" src="@Url.Action("Preview", "Pictures", new { id = m.Id} )"/>
```

The Image View is returned to a main view from my controller using a child action.

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("Gallery", "Pictures")
</div>

[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Gallery()
    {...}
```

Out of curiosity I tried to check if the `@Url.Action` is executed as child action or not but found that it is not executed as child action. I thought I knew the difference between MVC Actions and Child Actions but this has made me rethink. Can you explain why this is not considered a child action by the controller?

Comment: Why do you think an HTML helper for creating URLs should be responsible for making this kind of validation? You pass action and controller names as string. If you mistype one of them, you get an invalid URL.

Comment: That looks like an improper use of `Html.Raw` on `m.Title`. You probably want just `alt="@m.Title"`. I can't imagine why you would want to allow HTML to be placed in your `alt` text unescaped.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I dont think Html helper should be responsible for making this validation. i just want to learn in detail how MVC works.

Comment: When you mark an action with ChildActionOnly attribute, you tell the framework it cannot be called from a URL. You can only call it within other views and render its output. So trying to create a URL to that action is meaningless.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları The ChildAction is for gallery and not actual picture. Please read and process info before making assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child action is an action which is executed as part of an original action.  So your browser calls for Action 1 and during the Razor rendering of your view, your view calls `@Html.Action()` to render a child action. The child action is executed **before** the results of Action 1 are sent back to the client.

In your case, the "Preview" action (`@Url.Action()`) is being called by the browser.  This results in a 2nd action, not a child action because the results of the first action were returned to the browser and now your browser is calling for a new action.  Much like if the user clicked an `<a>` link to navigate to a new page.